# How to send `SIGINT` over `systemctl` to custom daemon/service

Tags: linux, shell, daemon

I have a script that I would like to run as service on my Linux machine, let's call it `my_script.sh`. It is executable and can be run over `./path/to/my_scrit.sh`.

I also have script that kills `my_script.sh`, let's call it `kill_my_scprit.sh`. The contents of `kill_my_script.sh` are:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sudo kill -SIGINT $(pgrep my_script)
```

In essence, this should mimic `Ctrl+C` for `my_script.sh`.

This works perfectly fine if I run the scripts from a terminal, i.e. in ttyX I run `./path/to/my_scrit.sh` to start it and in ttyY `./path/to/kill_my_scrit.sh` to initiate the shut down sequence of `my_script.sh`.

As mentioned before, the goal is to run this as deamon, so I created `/etc/systemd/system/my_script.service`

```bash
[Unit]
....

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/dir/
ExecStart=/path/to/my_script.sh
ExecStop=/path/to/kill_my_script.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
...
```

Using `sudo systemctl start my_script.service` starts the script as expected, but using `sudo systemctl stop my_script.service` starts the shutdown sequence for `my_script.sh`, but doesn't let it finish... Am I missing something? The shutdown sequence takes roughly 10sec...

Comment: Have you tried `TimeoutStopSec=15` ? https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did not know about this option! But yes, this in combination with `KillMode=process` solved the issue.

Comment: Cool - feel free to write up what you did as the answer so other folks can learn.